# Libgdx - didpose over and over?

Tags: java, libgdx

hey am a beginner in Libgdx. i am a bit confused about disposing the stuff.

```
Texture brickTexture;
Array<Brick> bricks;

public Game {
    brickTexture = new Texture("brick.png");
    bricks = new Array<Brick>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Brick brick = new Brick(i, brickTexture);
        bricks.add(brick);
    }
}

void dispose () {
    brickTexture.dispose(); // brick texture loaded in this class
    for (Brick brick : bricks) brick.brickTexture.dispose(); // disposing the public texture which was earlier passed on to the brick class
}
```

Should both of the lines be in the dispose method or only the first one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to do this once. It's the same Texture object so when you dispose it on any reference no other object can use it anymore. It's disposed.

Also you might want to check out [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) class, which handles disposing stuff for you.

Comment: thanx have used the same approach that u have told but i was in doubt that there might be a need to dispose for all objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "bricktexture" for every "Brick" in the ArrayList, so you are basically pointing to the same object so you should only dispose "bricktexture" once.

If you also want to "free" the array, probably you should call

```
bricks.clear();
```

Which will become empty (as with no elements inside).